# Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wants to check if the integer value is zero or other integer number using 'if' loop. I have done like this

```
 int ID = (int)Session["id"];//I have assigned Session["id"]=20; on previous page
    if (ID == 0 || ID =50)
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

but it shows an error Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'. Please help

Comment: `=` vs `==`. (Note: the `=` operator evaluates to the *value assigned* and thus also carries through said type in the expression: `x = int` is itself typed as `int`.)

Comment: Very poor question . and careless mistaken question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning 50 to ID..not comparing...It should be

```
if (ID == 0 || ID ==50)
```

Answer (score 3):

Correct your if block

```
if (ID == 0 || ID ==50)
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

Answer (score 3):

You want this:-

```
if (ID == 0 || ID ==50)
                   ^---> //Change here as you are not comparing you are assigning which is not correct as per your need
```

as `=` represents assignment and you want to do comparison. So you probably need to use `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

You have used"=" in if block instead of "=="

```
 if (ID == 0 || ID == 50)
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed the `==` there..

try below.

```
int ID = (int)Session["id"];//I have assigned Session["id"]=20; on previous page
    if (ID == 0 || ID == 50)
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```